# Where does MySQL store its databases on Debian?

Tags: debian, mysql, data-recovery

Our system crashed and we're trying to recover our data. The disc is fine, but the OS is gone, so I'm trying to get at the actual MySQL database files.

Does anybody know where to look for them in a Debian Linux server?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

MySQL stores DB files in `/var/lib/mysql` by default, but you can override this in the configuration file, typically called `/etc/my.cnf`, although Debian calls it `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.

Comment: In Debian default setup, you need to be root to view the contents of /var/lib/mysql, just to make it clear. As user, you'll see an almost empty directory if you do: ls /var/lib/mysql

Answer (score -1):

Check `/opt/lampp/var/mysql/` also. It is the database directory for the [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_linux.html) program.

Comment: It looks to me, based on searching for that path, like this path comes in with a package called Xampp.